# How to change directory in Google Developer Console

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, maven

Using the Google Developer Console Java Tutorial, I'm attempting to setup a Google App Engine Project. I am following the instructions on the Google Developer Console site but became stuck on the following:

Change to a directory where you want to build your project and invoke Maven as follows:

> mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.17
>   -Dapplication-id=your-app-id -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:

replacing `your-app-id` with the project ID value you obtained in the previous step.

How do you change the directory where you want to build your project and invoke Maven? I have the ZIP File but not sure how to change the directory.

PATH environment variable

> %M2%C:\Users\jbunn\Desktop\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.zip\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online
>   Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Microsoft Online
>   Services;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Users\jbunn\Desktop\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin

Answer (score 1):

You create your project locally. Create your project's folder structure with the mkdir command and traverse folders with the cd command. Or use a graphical file manager. Have a look at this quick start guide:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven-android/

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting stuck on the following "Add the bin folder to your path". I went into environment variables and added the directory where I unzipped Maven. After doing so, I ran mvn in the command prompt. However, CMD tells me that mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command. I feel like i am missing something. See attached PATH environment variable.

Comment: Since Maven relies on Java, I would avoid using your user profile directory. The recommended directory would be system root e.g. C:\apache-maven-3.2.5. Then add C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin to $PATH. Also double check by running mvn --version or mvn --help from within the bin folder, just in case you have a corrupted file.

Comment: Thx. I also missed a step in the Maven instructions where I had to install the %JAVA_HOME%\bin. This video was also a good resource. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jtj-0yhox5s